# Ubuntu couldn't detect my scanner

Tags: printing, hp, scanner

Ubuntu 16.04, GNOME.
Don't know why, but Simple Scan stoped working - firstly, the error "no devices was found", after reinstalling last version of hplip and configuring this problem was solved. But still after trying to press Scan button, or run scanimage -L infinite waiting is appeared (with animation of moving circles in Simple Scan). I've googled really a lot, but nothing works.

lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 03f0:042a Hewlett-Packard LaserJet M1132 MFP
```

sane-find-scanner:

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [Hewlett-Packard], product=0x042a [HP LaserJet Professional M1132 MFP]) at libusb:003:011
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

So, what can I do? /etc/hp/hplip.conf doesn't contain any interesting information, as I could see. File's owner is me, not root.

Comment: Personally, I have found gscan2pdf (downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Centre) to be more robust, It always seems to recognise my HP multifunction printer without issue, but the printer needs to be switched on before launching the software before it can function correctly.

Comment: HP provide a trouble-shooting link https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/KnowledgeBase/Troubleshooting and a section on scanning https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/KnowledgeBase/Troubleshooting/TroubleshootScanning that you could check through;